# Setting up negative binomial GLMM with multiple (8) predictor variables

Tags: java

I'm pretty new to R and I'm trying to create models using negative binomial GLMMs. The problem is, I have 1 response variable and I want to test 8 predictor variables for multicollinearity. It seems easy when, for example, there are only 3 predictor variables because that means only 4 possible combinations. However, I'm wondering if there is an easier way to set up all possible combinations for 8 different predictor variables when testing for multicollinearity without going through every combination by hand, which means some number far over 50 different combinations for 8 predictor variables to be tested against the response variable.

I've been using the `glm.nb` function in the `MASS` package and I'm unsure if there is a big difference between that and the `glmmTMB` package.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you seem to be interested to generate all combinations that have at least two values. A very neat way to do it is to create a map, like this:

```
Map<ValueType,Boolean> items = new Map<ValueType,Boolean>();
```

Where ValueType is the type of your values. Let's assume that you have an array called `values` where you have your actual values that you intend to work with. Let's fill the map using that:

```
for (int index = 0; index < values.length; index++) {
    map.put(index, false);
}
```

very nice. Now, let's create a numeric value that keeps track of the number of true values:

```
int combinationCount = 0;
```

and this is how you can generate and process your combinations, where the n values you have are represented as a boolean number of n digits, where each digit is inside a current combination if and only if its representative inside the map is true.

```
int top = 0;
while (top < values.length) {
    boolean stop = false;
    for (top = 0; (!stop) && (top < values.length); top++) {
        stop = !map.get(top);
        stop ? combinationCount++ : combinationCount--;
        map.put(stop);
        if (combinationCount >= 2) {
            for (int innerIndex = 0; innerIndex < values.length; innerIndex++) {
                if (map.get(innerIndex)) {
                    //values[innerIndex] is inside the current combination
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```